# Display hour intervals as 12:00 - 13:00

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a column that display a timestamp as follows:

- 2017-07-17 09:14:49.000
- 2017-07-17 10:07:15.000
- 2017-07-17 10:30:39.000
- 2017-07-17 10:33:40.000
- 2017-07-17 10:49:06.000
- 2017-07-17 11:16:48.000

I need to write a sql query that will display hourly intervals as follows:

- 09:00 - 10:00
- 10:00 - 11:00

Does anyone know how to achieve this? Currently I have no script because i'm not sure where to start.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you need an to see next to your timestamp column what interval does it belong or do you need all intervals listed?

Comment: Usually formatting result is responsibility of "client" code. For example in .net this will be very simple operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DATEPART` function to get `HOUR` part of your datetime

```
DATEPART(HOUR, Column1)
```

From there it's just string formatting to get the exact text you need

```
SELECT Column1
, RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, Column1) AS NVARCHAR(2)),2) + ':00 - ' 
+ RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, Column1)+1 AS NVARCHAR(2)),2) + ':00' AS Interval
FROM Table1
```

[SQLFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/79e23/1)

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly! Really appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT fieldname FROM my_table WHERE time(event_time) >= '10:00:00' AND time(event_time) < '11:00:00'
```

Etc.

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question. If you're looking to populate a Select control with the various time spans, you don't do that in SQL, but in whatever programming language you're using.